# Why isn't enqueued script in wordpress working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a Wordpress childtheme using a functions.php that contains the following:

```
    <?php
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_script' ); 
        function load_custom_script() { 
        wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wpw-custom.js',   array('jquery'), '1.0', true ); 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
      }
   ?>
```

*This is successfully loading my custom script, in the footer, AFTER jQuery itself loads.* The custom script contains the following testing code to let me know if the enqueue process works:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
alert( "ready!" );
});
```

I can view source on my pages and verify the successful loading of my wpw-custom.js but it is not executing the alert!

What have I done wrong or what steps can I take to methodically find out what I have done wrong? Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? What do you get if you type `$` in the console? Try replacing `$` with `jQuery`.

Comment: Thanks to you also Derek. THat is exactly what I should have done but I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery in WordPress runs in noConflict mode which means the global $ shortcut for jQuery isn't available. Replace your code with the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert( 'ready!' );
});
```

Inside the document ready wrapper the $ can be used as an alias for jQuery.

Comment: Yeah,(shame face) that was it. I know better too. Darnit. Thanks man.